# IndexOutOfBoundsException when using the write method on a Apache POI HSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to write a method that takes two HSSFSheets (from two different HSSFWorkbooks that are imported via a FileChooser) and makes sure that the name of each Row of Sheet1 (as in the first cell of each row of Sheet1) has to be the same  name as each Row of Sheet2. If it's not the case the method has to re-organize Sheet2 so as the names of each Row of Sheet2 should match those of Sheet1.

In the end the method should create and open a new excel file which should contain the reorganized Sheet2. And this is where the problem comes in

```
public void organizeSheets(HSSFSheet sheet1, HSSFSheet sheet2) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    HSSFWorkbook permutationWb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    HSSFSheet permutationSheet = permutationWb.createSheet();
    short noOfColumns;
    HSSFRow testrow = sheet1.getRow(0);
    short testcell = testrow.getLastCellNum();
    noOfColumns = testcell;
    int noOfRows = sheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
    short noOfColumns2;
    HSSFRow testrow2 = sheet2.getRow(0);
    short testcell2 = testrow2.getLastCellNum();
    noOfColumns2 = testcell2;

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfRows; i++) {
        if (!getValue(sheet1, 0, i).toString().equals(getValue(sheet2, 0, i).toString())) {

            System.out.println(getValue(sheet1, 0, i));
            System.out.println(getValue(sheet2, 0, i));
            int j = 0;

            while (!getValue(sheet1, 0, i).toString().equals(getValue(sheet2, 0, j).toString())) {
                j = j + 1;
            }

            HSSFRow transitionRow1 = permutationSheet.createRow(0);
            HSSFRow transitionRow2 = permutationSheet.createRow(1);

            for (int l=0; l < noOfColumns2; l++) {
                transitionRow1.createCell(l);
                transitionRow1.getCell(l).setCellValue(getValue(sheet2, l, j));
                //System.out.println(transitionRow1.getCell(l));
            }

            for (int p=0; p < noOfColumns2; p++) {
                transitionRow2.createCell(p);
                transitionRow2.getCell(p).setCellValue(getValue(sheet2, p, i));
            }


            for (int k=0; k < noOfColumns2; k++) {
                sheet2.getRow(j).getCell(k).setCellValue(getValue(permutationSheet, k, 1).toString());
                sheet2.getRow(i).getCell(k).setCellValue(getValue(permutationSheet, k, 0).toString());

            }
        }
    }
    sheet2.getWorkbook().write(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\PC HP\\Desktop\\organized.xls"));
    sheet2.getWorkbook().close();
    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("C:\\Users\\PC HP\\Desktop\\organized.xls"));

}
```

getValue(sheet, row, column) allows me to get the value of the cell whose coordinates are in the arguments of the method.

Here's the error message I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Block 33 not found
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.getBlockAt(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:486)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSStream$StreamBlockByteBufferIterator.next(NPOIFSStream.java:169)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSStream$StreamBlockByteBufferIterator.next(NPOIFSStream.java:142)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NDocumentInputStream.readFully(NDocumentInputStream.java:248)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NDocumentInputStream.read(NDocumentInputStream.java:150)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.DocumentInputStream.read(DocumentInputStream.java:125)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.isPropertySetStream(PropertySet.java:336)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySet.<init>(PropertySet.java:241)
at org.apache.poi.hpsf.PropertySetFactory.create(PropertySetFactory.java:92)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.getPropertySet(POIDocument.java:211)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.getPropertySet(POIDocument.java:168)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.readProperties(POIDocument.java:141)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.getSummaryInformation(POIDocument.java:108)
at org.apache.poi.POIDocument.writeProperties(POIDocument.java:260)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1377)
at model.main.organizeSheets(main.java:377)
at model.main.main(main.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Unable to read 512 bytes from 17408 in stream of length -1
at     org.apache.poi.poifs.nio.ByteArrayBackedDataSource.read(ByteArrayBackedDataSource.java:42)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.getBlockAt(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:484)
... 16 more
```

I believe that there is no problem with the actual switch between the rows of Sheet2 (I've tested with prints, I might be wrong if I didn't test enough) and I have no idea how to deal with this situation.

In order to instantiate Sheet2, the code asks the user to chose a workbook from his computer then choose a sheet within the workbook like follows

```
excelworkbook1 = o.chooseFile1();
    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sheetnumber1 = Integer.parseInt(scanner1.nextLine());
    excelsheet1 = o.chooseSheet(excelworkbook1, sheetnumber1);

public HSSFWorkbook chooseFile1() throws IOException {
    JFrame frame = null;
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(frame);
    String filepath = new String();

    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        filepath = fc.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalPath();
        setFile1Adress(filepath);
    } else {
        System.exit(1);
    }

    FileInputStream file1InputStream;
    file1InputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath);

    NPOIFSFileSystem file;

    file = new NPOIFSFileSystem(file1InputStream);

    HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file.getRoot(), true);
    file.close();

    return workbook;
}

 public HSSFSheet chooseSheet(HSSFWorkbook excelfile, int entry) {
    return excelfile.getSheetAt(entry - 1);
}
```

Comment: How is `sheet2` instantiated (show the code)?

Comment: I edited the post so you can see it

Comment: Switch to Apache POI 3.15 beta 3 and you can use [`write(File)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html#write(java.io.File)) to simplify and speed up the writing, see the [FAQ for details](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1023C)